# Index to facilitate joining a table against itself to gather the last observation

Tags: oracle, index, join, index-tuning

I have a discrete step timeseries table where I insert about 1M rows per "month end" with the identifier being the last day of the month (2018/02/28 or 2018/08/31). I try to keep as many months as possible in this table so that we can construct month-to-month change reports that go as far back as possible.

for example, the data looks similar to this:

```
| p_key | monthend_id | val |
|-------|-------------|-----| 
| 0     | 8/31/2018   | 100 | 
| 0     | 7/31/2018   | 90  | 
| 0     | 6/30/2018   | 110 | 
| 1     | 8/31/2018   | 25  | 
| 1     | 7/31/2018   | 31  | 
| 1     | 6/30/2018   | 22  |
```

To do this, I need to match the table to itself where the two are exactly 1 month apart. Right now I have a query that runs with a join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthend_table t1 LEFT JOIN monthend_table t2
ON t1.p_id = t2.p_id 
AND to_char(add_months(t1.monthend_source, -1), 'YYYY/MM') = 
to_char(t2.monthend_source, 'YYYY/MM')
```

This works fine, and I may even be able to take out the character formatting, however I notice in my execution plan that the index on `monthend_source` isn't being used, and so it's doing 2 full scans.

How would I best construct indexes that would facilitate the fastest join possible?

Should I create one for `(p_id, to_char(monthend_source, 'YYYY/MM'))` and another for `(pid, to_char(add_months(monthend_source, -1), 'YYYY/MM'))`? Is a single index better?

I often find I struggle to know when and how to create effective indices in (what is to me) more complicated situations like these, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To create a "month-to-month change report", I recommend using Oracle 12c's `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` feature.